# Paypal/Stripe to bank account

Tags: node.js, paypal, stripe-payments

Sorry, I am not good in english and I can't google a right answer, but I am developing an app where I transfer money from bank account to credit and then I need to make payment from paypal/stripe account to bank account.

Is it possible?

I am using Node JS with Stripe and Paypal package.

I found some answers that in Stripe it's possible only for US accounts.
I am from Slovakia, is it possible also for Slovakian accounts?

Can you please provide an example in Node JS?

I found out that payouts are something I should use for that problem.
But I always get this response from paypal api:

```
{ batch_header: 
{ payout_batch_id: 'EMM899S342TTE',
 batch_status: 'DENIED',
 time_created: '2017-06-25T20:48:40Z',
 time_completed: '2017-06-25T20:48:41Z',
 sender_batch_header: 
  { email_subject: 'You have a payment',
    sender_batch_id: 'q7g9i765b9lkvjkyb9' },
 amount: { currency: 'USD', value: '0.9' },
 fees: { currency: 'USD', value: '0.02' } },
 items: 
  [ { payout_item_id: 'LJ7EQA952LBR2',
   transaction_status: 'FAILED',
   payout_item_fee: [Object],
   payout_batch_id: 'EMM899S342TTE',
   payout_item: [Object],
   errors: [Object],
   links: [Object] } ],
  links: 
   [ { href: 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payouts/EMM899S342TTE',
   rel: 'self',
   method: 'GET' } ],
  httpStatusCode: 201 }
```

So I found out that `response.items[0].errors` have this error:

```
{ name: 'INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS',
  message: 'Sender has insufficient funds',
  information_link: 
'https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch/#errors' 
}
```

So I will debug it more deeply...

So I found out that I have to do the Business account with some testing amount and now I get this error:

```
{ name: 'ACCOUNT_UNCONFIRMED_EMAIL ',
  message: 'Sender\'s email is not confirmed',
  information_link: 'https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch/#errors' }
```